# mysql regex expression build up

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am stuck on a mysql regular expression.

[image: table image]

from this table i want to select all the rows which has teacher id 4 including 84,4 teacher id. what would be the regular expression for this query?

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM research 
WHERE teacher_id REGEXP '4'|'^4,$+'|'+^,4$'
```

so far i have tried this.

Comment: Storing comma-separated values in a database is a typical sign that the database design is poor - you should always avoid storing comma-separated values in the database!

Comment: Try using [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) if you really must use this method of storing values.

Comment: @Qirel, I am just learning things. Next time i will definitely avoid using comma separated value. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @NigelRen, i will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
SELECT * 
FROM research 
WHERE teacher_id REGEXP '(,|^)4(,|$)'
```

The `(,|^)4(,|$)` regex requires `,` or start of string before `4` and a comma or end of string after it.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mr3N4p/1).

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and perhaps faster:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(4, teacher_id)
```